# react-google-recaptcha allow CSP

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha, content-security-policy, helmet.js, react-google-recaptcha

I'm using react js one of the forms I used react-google-captcha and worked perfectly when build and the backend I use helmet which provides CSP security and other errors came up

[image]

after searching to lot of sites i add the following meta tag

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="script-src 'self' https://www.google.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/;
  frame-src https://www.google.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/"
/>
```

still no luck. have you encounter this problem? can share with me the solution. Thanks in advance

in my helmet configuration [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helmet maintainer here.

This is happening because of something called Content Security Policy, which Helmet sets by default. Helmet sets it in an HTTP header, which overrides what you've put in that `<meta>` tag.

To solve your problem, you will need to configure Helmet's CSP.

[MDN has a good documentation about CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) which I would recommend reading for background. After that, take a look at [Helmet's README](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/) to see how to configure its CSP component.

To give some help specific to this question, let's take a look at one error you're seeing:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://google.com/recaptcha/...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". ...
```

This error is telling you that the `script-src` directive of your CSP does not allow JavaScript to load from `google.com/recaptcha`, and so it was blocked.

There are several ways to fix this:

1. Update your CSP to allow JavaScript to load from Google. You'd do something like this:

   ```
   app.use(
     helmet({
       contentSecurityPolicy: {
         useDefaults: true,
         directives: {
           "script-src": ["'self'", "google.com"],
         },
       },
     })
   );
   ```
2. Refactor your app to avoid loading the CAPTCHA. Probably not possible, but it is an available solution.
3. Disable CSP. This is the most dangerous option so I don't recommend it.

   ```
   app.use(
     helmet({
       contentSecurityPolicy: false,
     })
   );
   ```

In summary: to solve your problem, you will need to tell Helmet to configure your CSP.

Comment: Hi @Evan, when I tried the solution same error appeared and I also try to clear cache etc. i edited my question above with new helmet configuration still no luck

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to @evanHahn configuration are now working to solve the problem you need to configure the helmet in your backend below the ss.

```
app.use(
helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
      "script-src": ["'self'", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/", "https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/"],
      "frame-src": ["'self'", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/", "https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/"],
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to share code, this makes it hard for other people to use your answer if they have the same or a similar issue